# Sum up appended input value with the current total using jquery

Tags: jquery, sum

I'm trying to re-calculate the total existing value when a user is typing in the new value in the appended input element. My system is able to do the sum up but the calculation is wrong as it will keep on adding in the number even though the input number is updated.

For example the original total is `400`. When user is inserting `2` at first, the total will change to 402. But as the user type in and the input value become `23` the new amount become `425` when it's supposed to be `423`

**HTML**

```
<p id="total">400</p>
<div id="appended"></div>

<a href="#" onClick="AddRow()">Add Row</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#appended').on('input', '.amount', function(){
    var amount = parseFloat($(this).val());
  var total  = parseFloat($('#total').text())
  var new_total = amount+total;
  
  $('#total').text(new_total)
})
```

Working code can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/foek1846/

Comment: Save the initial total in a variable first?

Comment: How? I don't see any difference from doing so.

Comment: If you save the initial total in a persistent variable, you won't be overwriting it, so you'll get the results you want

Comment: Mind to give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the initial `total` in a variable first:

```js
const origTotal = Number($('#total').text());

function AddRow() {
  $('#appended').append(`<input class="form-control amount" value="" />`);
}

$('#appended').on('input', '.amount', function() {
  const amountSum = [...$('.amount')]
    .map(input => Number(input.value))
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  $('#total').text(origTotal + amountSum)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="total">400</p>
<div id="appended"></div>

<a href="#" onClick="AddRow()">Add Row</a>
```